# ALOS/PALSAR High Q DEM 12.5 Accuracy

Tags: dem, remote-sensing

Does anyone know the XYZ accuracy for the Phased Array L-band Synthetic Aperture Radar (PALSAR) DEMs (12.5 x 12.5 px)?

Is there a document for reference?

Comment: Did you seee https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/a/alos-2 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the DEMs included with the ALOS PALSAR RTC products available from ASF, the source and resolution varies. These DEMs are NOT generated from ALOS PALSAR data. They are the DEMs that were used for RTC processing, which were simply mosaicked and clipped from publicly-available DEMs, such as SRTM and NED. They have been resampled to match the pixel spacing of the RTC product (12.5m for the high-res product), but that is NOT an indication of the original DEM resolution, which varies depending on which DEM provides coverage for the granule processed for RTC.

Refer to https://asf.alaska.edu/data-sets/derived-data-sets/alos-palsar-rtc/alos-palsar-radiometric-terrain-correction/#dem_information for more information about the DEMs included with the ALOS PALSAR RTC products.